# error in C# windows forms for database backup

Tags: c#, sql-server

Please let me know where is the error in my below code,

The code is:

```
public void Backup(PL_DbBackup objPl)
{
        try
        {
            string qry = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + objPl.Database + "] TO DISK '" + objPl.BackupLoc + "\\" + "Database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(qry, objCon);

            objCon.Open();
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            objPl.Status = "ok";
            objCon.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { throw e; }
    }
```

To get DB name:

```
objPl.Database = objCon.Database.ToString();
```

What exactly comes in the query is, when i execute the compiler shows this result i.e:

```
qry = "BACKUP DATABASE [DW_Database] TO DISK 'G:\\backup\\Database-2017-03-03-22-00-00.bak'"
```

The error is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'G:\backup\Database-2017-03-03-20-10-40.bak'

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't use the '=' sign after the key word 'To DISK'**

the below query is working well

```
string qry = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + objPl.Database + "] TO DISK ='" + objPl.BackupLoc + "\\" + "Database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";
```